# How to check if valid facebook url, before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to check, if the url a user have posted in my form is a valid facebook url. I am aware of the regx `(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?`

But how to use it, am i not sure on how to do?

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <b>Facebook Url</b>
        <input id="FacebookUrl" name="FacebookUrl" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make a form validation on that, that checks the facebook regx? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the button onclick event:

```
<button id="SendBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="return validateUrl();">Send</button>
```

And then you can open a script tag in the same file or other file and implement your regex.

```
function validateUrl() {
  url = $("#FacebookUrl").val();
  var pattern = /^(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*)?$/;
  if(pattern.test(url)) {
    alert("Correct URL");
  }
  else {
    alert("Incorrect URL");
  }
  return pattern.test(url);
}
```

And with this result prevent the action.

Comment: Thanks Randall. If i should add a "alert()" to check if it should work, would that jus be placed under "return parrern.test(url); :)

Comment: Add it before the return.

Comment: It does alert no matter what? Could yoou try make it so that if valid it alert("valid") and if not valid it return alert("not valid") ??

Comment: @JonesKing please accept this answer if it answers your request.

Comment: Randall It says Incorrect URL on a profile url? Is that just the wornng regex or what?

Comment: @JonesKing, for me is working ok with a profile. Test this: https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow If you add more signs after the profile, then the regex is not the right one for you.

Comment: It works thanks! Donn't know why it denie this url: https://www.facebook.com/rasmus.vejbynielsen But other url's works! Thannks :)